# how to merge three dictionaries and removing common key values and rearrange it in ascending order?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, machine-learning

```
dict 1={99: [2.35, nan, 4.31], 200: [2.02, nan, nan],314: [1.94, nan, nan],749: [21.75, nan, nan],964: [25.73, nan, nan],1232: [64.42, nan, nan],1486: [95.46, nan, nan],1620: [120.96, nan, nan],1851: [60.19, nan, nan],1886: [57.64, nan, nan],2034: [34.32, nan, nan],2086: [35.16, nan, nan],2368: [25.17, nan, nan]}

dict2={101: [nan, 21.67, nan],287: [nan, 20.23, nan],738: [nan, 77.4, nan],897: [nan, 86.6, nan],1235: [nan, 138.77, nan],1490: [nan, 187.46, nan],1668: [nan, 216.83, nan],1894: [nan, 130.03, nan],2345: [nan, 75.26, 15.9]}

dict3= {99: [2.35, nan, 4.31],205: [nan, nan, 4.08],308: [nan, nan, 3.32],448: [nan, nan, 5.79],570: [nan, nan, 7.04],748: [nan, nan, 10.85],994: [nan, nan, 19.56],1237: [nan, nan, 33.89],1415: [nan, nan, 35.21],1618: [nan, nan, 41.38],1676: [nan, nan, 40.11],1899: [nan, nan, 25.51],1986: [nan, nan, 21.45],2039: [nan, nan, 22.56],2337: [nan, nan, 16.71],2345: [nan, 75.26, 15.9]}
```

Comment: You should show your code. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you're woring with relatively small dict's this is a straithforward solution:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan
# here i replicate your data
dict1={99: [2.35, nan, 4.31], 200: [2.02, nan, nan],314: [1.94, nan, nan],749: [21.75, nan, nan],964: [25.73, nan, nan],1232: [64.42, nan, nan],1486: [95.46, nan, nan],1620: [120.96, nan, nan],1851: [60.19, nan, nan],1886: [57.64, nan, nan],2034: [34.32, nan, nan],2086: [35.16, nan, nan],2368: [25.17, nan, nan]}
dict2={101: [nan, 21.67, nan],287: [nan, 20.23, nan],738: [nan, 77.4, nan],897: [nan, 86.6, nan],1235: [nan, 138.77, nan],1490: [nan, 187.46, nan],1668: [nan, 216.83, nan],1894: [nan, 130.03, nan],2345: [nan, 75.26, 15.9]}
dict3= {99: [2.35, nan, 4.31],205: [nan, nan, 4.08],308: [nan, nan, 3.32],448: [nan, nan, 5.79],570: [nan, nan, 7.04],748: [nan, nan, 10.85],994: [nan, nan, 19.56],1237: [nan, nan, 33.89],1415: [nan, nan, 35.21],1618: [nan, nan, 41.38],1676: [nan, nan, 40.11],1899: [nan, nan, 25.51],1986: [nan, nan, 21.45],2039: [nan, nan, 22.56],2337: [nan, nan, 16.71],2345: [nan, 75.26, 15.9]}

# merge the dict's
dict_unsorted = {**dict1, **dict2, **dict3}

# put the keys in a list and sort them
keys = list(dict_unsorted.keys())
keys.sort()

# make a sorted list
dict_sorted = {}
for key in keys:
    dict_sorted[key] = dict_unsorted[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this question needs some clarification - what do you do if there is a key collision and the values are different? Most likely, you'd want a list of values.

With this assumption, you can create a new dict and loop through your data dictionaries with the following logic:

1. If the key doesn't exist, insert the key and append the value.
2. If the key exists, loop through the list of values and check if the current value is in the list.

   1. If the current value exists, continue.
   2. If the current value does not exist, append the value to the list.